# Why is the "gptr" type of basic_streambuf char_type* rather than const char_type*?

Tags: c++, iostream, const-correctness, streambuf

The `basic_streambuf` member to set the three "gptrs" of the streambuf, `setg`, is declared as:

```
protected:
  void setg(char_type *gback, char_type *gptr, char_type *egptr);
```

I am wondering: why was the type of each gptr made `char_type*` instead of `const char_type*`? Is it safe to use `const_cast` here to use const char pointers for these gptrs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not const because the `streambuf` interface doesn't know how you're populating the buffer. For example the `underflow` and `uflow` methods may pull *n* bytes from a file or similar and populate the extant buffer of the streambuf. You may also be using the same storage for the buffers for a read/write stream stream. The streambuf is a buffer, a cache if you will. It sits between the formatting functionality of the `[io]stream` and the actual underlying character stream (usually a file). It's a window on to that underlying stream, and it makes sense to reuse the storage for that window (which means it's probably not const).

Is it safe to cast away the const-ness? Maybe. It will depend on the actual streambuf implementation and how it is used.

Comment: Of course! :)  I was confused because I am currently writing a streambuf for a constant C-string. For my purpose, `underflow` and `uflow` aren't used. Silly me. +1 as well for writing a really nice answer.